# Filter API request according header auth token

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I would like to filter the objects according to the token header which gets sent with the GET requests.

My request is sending the token in the header (`get curl -H "Authorization: Token 3f3f3fzzz" https://1.com/api`)

The code below returns no results (just an empty array- no error). I am unable to determine where my request object headers are.

My guess is that I need some middleware function to mutate the response and put the user object in it too.

**views.py**

```
class AllViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Movie.objects.order_by('-created',)
    serializer_class = AllSerializer
    def get_queryset(self):
        Movie.objects.filter(owner = self.request.user)
```

I tried some debugging after the def_queryset (using `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()`).

`def(sel.request)` returns: http://dpaste.com/2VQARE3

Here are other parts of my code which may be relevant.

**models.py**

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
def create_auth_token(sender, instance=None, created=False, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Token.objects.create(user=instance)

class Movie(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField("Title", max_length=10000, blank=True)
    tag = models.ManyToManyField('Tag', blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField("Created", auto_now_add=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', blank=True, null=True)
```

**setting.py**

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': ('rest_framework.filters.DjangoFilterBackend',),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    )
}

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)
```

Comment: You don't need middleware you need to implement filter backend. What exactly do you mean filter by token. Token is representation of user. So you want to filter by user?

Comment: Correct, filter by the user (which is represented by the header token)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write custom filter backend http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#custom-generic-filtering

```
from rest_framework import filters
class OwnerFilterBackend(filters.BaseFilterBackend):
    def filter_queryset(self, request, queryset, view):
        return queryset.filter(owner=request.user)

class AllViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    filter_backends = (OwnerFilterBackend,)
    ...
```

Comment: Awesome! Could you give me an example for when I POST/PUT? so it carries the correct user. Would it belong on the serializer?

Comment: @Ycon what do you mean by POST/PUT carries the correct user?

Comment: I've created another question- will be clearer. Thx- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480482

Answer (score 1):

If you want this view to always return the queryset of the owner's Movies, you can access the header through the request object's [self.request.META](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/) (headers should be available, look at content type in the docs) then decode the token to find the associated user connected to it.

so in your queryset

```
def get_queryset(self):
   access_token = self.request.META.get('TOKEN')
   user_from_token = find_user_given_token(access_token)
   return Movie.objects.filter(owner = user_from_token)
```

alternatively, if meta is not available for some odd reason or configuration, you can pass the token via a query param. `'https://1.com/api?token= 3f3f3fzzz'`

then in your view, you have access to it via `self.request.query_params['token']`

additionally, you need to provide how you get the token in order to decipher how to decode the token.

Comment: Thanks but what am I supposed to do with `find_user_given_token(access_token)` part?

Also, in your example I've used the debugger after the line `access_token = self.request.META.get('TOKEN')`. However, typing 'access_token' returns blank.

Comment: A token is generated by serializing the user after authentication. That same class you use to encode the user should have the logic to decode the user.  I edited my answer to provide alternative solutions