# Post API using Token from header

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am posting using an API to create a new entry in the model Movie. Using headers, I would like to be able to POST so the OWNER is the user who has posted it. The users token is sent via headers.

**models.py**

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
def create_auth_token(sender, instance=None, created=False, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Token.objects.create(user=instance)

class Movie(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField("Title", max_length=10000, blank=True)
    tag = models.ManyToManyField('Tag', blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField("Created", auto_now_add=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', blank=True, null=True)
```

**Views.py**

```
class OwnerFilterBackend(filters.BaseFilterBackend):
    def filter_queryset(self, request, queryset, view):
        return queryset.filter(owner=request.user)

class AllViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    filter_backends = (OwnerFilterBackend,)
    queryset = Movie.objects.order_by('-created',).exclude(deleted=True).exclude(typetask=2)
    serializer_class = AllSerializer
```

**Serializers.py**

```
class AllSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tag = TagSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Movie
        fields = ('title', 'mail', 'pk', 'tag', 'info', 'created', 'deleted', 'status', 'typetask')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        tags_data = validated_data.pop('tag')
        movie = Movie.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for tag_data in tags_data:
            tag_qs = Tag.objects.filter(name__iexact=tag_data['name'])
            if tag_qs.exists():
                tag = tag_qs.first()
            else:
                tag = Tag.objects.create(**tag_data)
            task.tag.add(tag)
        return movie
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set user using `context['request']` of form, which is provided by default in `GenericAPIView`s. http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#including-extra-context

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    tags_data = validated_data.pop('tag')
    owner = self.context['request'].user
    movie = Movie.objects.create(owner=owner, **validated_data)
    for tag_data in tags_data:
        tag_qs = Tag.objects.filter(name__iexact=tag_data['name'])
        if tag_qs.exists():
            tag = tag_qs.first()
        else:
            tag = Tag.objects.create(**tag_data)
        task.tag.add(tag)
    return movie
```

Comment: This has not worked. Do I need to import something? I'm not using genericAPIViews. I'm just using standard serializers. I used PDB to debug- it told me on `self.request` *** AttributeError: 'TaskSerializer' object has no attribute 'request'

Comment: @Ycon What do you mean `self.request`? it should be `self.context['request']`.

Comment: Ah you're right. So `self.context['request']` gives me `<rest_framework.request.Request object at 0x10ad0d310>`. I used `.__dict__` to see inside- and I it contains the Token object. However it doesn't reach my field.

Comment: @Ycon I gave you example read more carefully)) it should be `movie.owner = self.context['request'].user` to assign user from request

Comment: Yep, I've done that and I can see the token object inside. However, it does not seem to actually apply it to the creation of the model.

Comment: @Ycon Ah. I know why. Because we are not saving changes. it should be `owner = self.context['request'].user movie = Movie.objects.create(owner=owner, **validated_data)`. or you should call `movie.save()` after setting `movie.owner` See updated answer.